# Do we have any English dictionary that shows precisely both letters and diacritics?

Tags: dictionaries, phonetics

Dictionary uses IPA to depict the sound. However, most of them do not include diacritics, and thus it is very hard for learner to distinguish the sound.

See this quote from [Wiki](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/International_Phonetic_Alphabet)

> IPA symbols are composed of one or more elements of two basic types,
>   letters and diacritics. For example, the sound of the English letter
>   ⟨t⟩ may be transcribed in IPA with a single letter, [t], or with a
>   letter plus diacritics, [t̺ʰ], depending on how precise one wishes to
>   be.[note 2] Often, slashes are used to signal broad or phonemic
>   transcription; thus, /t/ is less specific than, and could refer to,
>   either [t̺ʰ] or [t], depending on the context and language.

For example, see this word "**Thai**" `/taɪ/` in http://dictionary.cambridge.org/dictionary/english/thai

I think it should be depicted as `t̺ʰai` since `t` generates quite a lot of air.

**So, Do we have any English dictionary that shows precisely both letters and diacritics?**

Comment: Maybe 1/3 of the /t/s in English *must* be aspirated. Maybe 1/3 of the /t/s in English *cannot* be aspirated. And maybe 1/3 of them are optional. So to represent the pronunciation of the /t/, you need three more symbols, one of which doesn't exist in IPA.

Comment: Dictionaries don't provide exact representations (phonology or semantics).They only have enough space. If one can still maintain a phonetic/phonemic distinction, the phonetics is too subtle for a native speaker, and the phonetics is too complicated for all the worlds other speakers. So no I don't think there's any dictionary to get you what you want. But try http://forvo.com/ which sounds them out.

Comment: [en.wiktionary.org](https://en.wiktionary.org) fairly often includes narrow transcriptions. e.g. ["top"](https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/top#Pronunciation) /tɑp/, [tʰɑˀp].

Comment: I’m voting to close this question because it belongs on ELU.meta.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Diacritics—as opposed to normal, phonemic IPA transcriptions—are not good for dictionary entries for several reasons. The most important of these is that an individual speaker will vary their pronunciation of a word in different environments. Each different type of pronunciation would require different diacritics. Many other things can affect a person's pronunciation of a word:

- who they are speaking to
- the register they are using
- how formal the context is
- whether they are reading, performing, mimicking, or speaking to a friend
- how much emphasis they wish to put on a word or part of a word
- what word came before this word
- what word came after this word
- whether the word is stressed
- whether the word is accented (carries musical stress)
- whether the word carries the tonic syllable in the utterance
- whether they are tired, sleepy, drunk, excited, cold, scared and so forth

Even if we could fix all of those parameters, speakers may produce the same word differently within the same sentence.

A non-native speaker trying to learn how to pronounce English, would be much better off learning about the general rules and descriptions of English phonetics and phonology so that they can apply these to new items rather than trying to read the fine diacritics from somebody's narrow transcription. So for example, knowing that the initial /t/ of a word is likely to be aspirated in most circumstances is better than reading a transcription of a word and checking if the initial /t/ is aspirated in that transcription. A general understanding of English phonetics tell you that the initial /t/ in *Thai* will probably be aspirated without needing to squint at diacritics.

Comment: This is letting the perfect be the enemy of the good.

Comment: @GregLee I don't understand? The IPA transcription on its own can be thought of as 'perfect', but how can giving diactritics for things like devoicing, labialisation glotalling, glottal reinforcement aspiration and so forth which are all extremely context dependent give us an idea of the perfect?

Comment: Using diacritics can give a good idea of pronunciation.  You argue that diacritics could not give a perfect description of every speaker's pronunciation on every occasion, and therefore diacritics should not be used.  The overall structure of your argument is: diacritics may be good, but they're not perfect, therefore we shouldn't use them.

Comment: See here: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Perfect_is_the_enemy_of_good

Comment: The fact it's a lot of information does not mean it wouldn't be helpful. Even with variations among speakers, there are patterns that are useful to know. A dictionary that tells you that "button" is often realized [ˈbʌʔn̩], or that "what" is often realized (flapped) [wʌɾ] or (glottalized) [wʌˀ] is better, everything else being equal, than one that does not.

Comment: @FabienSnauwaert Hmm. Well, I see why you say that, but I can't agree. The variants you list are all analagous to the question of whether we need to write in the aspiration for every word initial /p, t/ or /k/. You can either learn that word initial plosives are all aspirated or you can try and memorise the phonetics for every single word. Similarly that's true for glottalisation, or flapping. And you've only used the allophonic variation there that you particularly find interesting. Not ones that would actually help learners ...

Comment: @FabienSnauwaert For example, in terms of leaners consider the word *beat*, /bi:t/ and contrast this with the word *bead*, /bi:d/. the most important info for a learner there is that the vowel in *beat* is half the length of the vowel in *bead*. That's how we know which word is which. The /d/ in *bead* will be devoiced if the word is followed by a voiceless consonant or a pause. Now you could give the (approximately nine) variants on the final consonant of *beat*, which would be pretty useless and also difficult to memorise, or you could give them the info that the vowel will be half its ...

Comment: @FabienSnauwaert normal length. The latter is the only info that will affect their intelligibility or their understanding. However, I doubt you or anyone else have ever dreamed of putting that kind of info in a dictionary transcription. The other thing is that, taking a word like *what*, you only list the variants that a leaner who knew what a glottal stop or a flap was would already be able to predict (and would rarely use incorrectly. For example no learners use a glottal stop or a flap for a word-initial /t/). The fact is that ...

Comment: @FabienSnauwaert there are probably thirty odd possible pronunciations of *what*, depending on what the preceding and following words are. Just taking the final /t/ there, it could be a canonical /t/, could be a glottal stop, could be glottally reinforced, could be flapped, could be ejective, could be unreleased, could have a lateral release, could have a nasal release, could be assimilated to a /p/, could be assimilated to a /k/ (and note that the /p / or /k/ could also be glottally reinforced etc), it could be assimilated to an /s/, could partake in coalescent assimilation and become /tʃ/...

Comment: @FabienSnauwaert It could even be elided, in other words dropped from the pronunciation. Suppose we take all of those and combine them with the fact that the vowel may be either /ʌ/ or /ə/ and depending on the previous word may be nasalised and the same is true for the /w/, we have way too much info for a learner to wade through. In each case, it's better for the learner to understand about allophonic variation rather than trying to remember all the different possible phonetic forms!!!

Comment: @FabienSnauwaert I am still sympathetic to your viewpoint, however. I just can't bring myself to agree with it for practical reasons of many kinds. :-)

Comment: PS. Let me know if you've read all of these comments here, and I'll delete them! Thanks.

Comment: @Araucaria-Nothereanymore. I see your point that such info would be overwhelming. But phonemic transcriptions are oversimplified. In the end, isn't the question what's helpful? I'd love to be able to check the detailed phonetic transcription of any utterance to know what sounds native and what sounds foreign. (Why not in an electronic dictionary? If not all forms, why not the main ones? If not all combos, at least the component parts.) Beyond dictionaries, if you're aware of a book that contains an *exhaustive* list of allophonic variations for American English I'd love to hear about it. :-)